# How to make element appear 2nd in two-column layout and 3rd when stacked with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've got the following layout using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/):

```
[1][2]
[3]
```

It stacks in one column on handheld devices like this:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

I need it to stack like this:

```
[1]
[3]
[2]
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature in Bootstrap called [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

Here is an [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/grsj4mpn/) for your needs:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 ">
        Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-5">
        Content 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-5">
        Content 2
    </div>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use nesting like this..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        2
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/view/NxRorezDfU